# Append the string provided by __FUNCTION__ macro

Tags: c++, macros

I have defined a macro as following:

```
#define ADD_TIME_ENTRY(_name_)   m_pTimeMeasurement->addTimeEntry(_name_);
```

Now, I want to pass the function name through `ADD_TIME_ENTRY()` in whichsoever function I put `ADD_TIME_ENTRY()`

`ADD_TIME_ENTRY(__FUNCTION__)` works fine for me but now, I want to add "_start" or "_stop" at the end of the function name. I mean, I need something like `"imageFunction()_start"` but I am not able to do it.

I want to do it in a single line i.e.

```
imageFunction()
{
    ADD_TIME_ENTRY(__FUNCTION__ ....something here...);
}
```

Comment: @Serthy: Sorry, it did not work.

Comment: @Serthy, `__FUNCTION__` is a `const char[]` variable, not a preprocessor macro, so you can't concatenate another string to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional macro `#define STRINGIZE(str) #str` and use it like this: `ADD_TIME_ENTRY(__FUNCTION__ STRINGIZE(start))`

---

Seems like `__FUNCTION__` might be not a macro so it is not particularly easy to combine it with anything in such a case. In MSVC2013 it is a macro so it is easy combinable. For other compilers I'd try the following:

```
#define GIVE_ME_NAME(tag) std::string(__FUNCTION__) + STRINGIZE(tag)
```

Not particularly efficient but working way.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define STRINGIZE(str) #str
#define GIVE_ME_NAME(tag) std::string(__FUNCTION__) + STRINGIZE(tag)

int main()
{
    std::cout << GIVE_ME_NAME(start);
};
```

Comment: I have written `ADD_TIME_ENTRY(__FUNCTION__ APPEND_STR("start"));` in a fuction but I am getting an error that `ERROR: a ')' expected`.

Comment: @skm, If your `APPEND_STR` is like mine `STRINGIZE` then remove quotes.

Comment: I even tried that too but I am getting the same error. I using VS2010

Comment: @skm, show all the code you have for these macro and how you use them. I don't have msvc2010 to test on but it works pretty well on 2013

Comment: `#define ADD_TIME_ENTRY(_name_)` and `#define APPEND_STR(str) #str` are the two macros. And, then I try to use `ADD_TIME_ENTRY(__FUNCTION__ APPEND_STR(start));` which is giving an error.

Comment: @skm, it should be at least `#define ADD_TIME_ENTRY(_name_) _name_`

Comment: I made it `#define ADD_TIME_ENTRY(_name_) _name_` but still the same error.

Comment: @skm, well my best guess is that in MSVS2010 the `__FUNCTION__` is not a macro like it is not in at least GCC. So it's not easy to deal with it then

Comment: Sorry, now there is no error but it is not printing anything. Actually, getting the function name and putting "start/stop" after it is not the only thing which `ADD_TIME_ENTRY()` is doing. It can be seen in my question that it is a macro which is calling a method of an another class and passing the name of that function using `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: @skm, you can use it like this: `ADD_TIME_ENTRY(GIVE_ME_NAME(start))` but since `GIVE_ME_NAME` returns nothing to you then I don't know what else I can do. Either MSVC2010 is broken or you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

As `__FUNCTION`__ is of type static "const char `__FUNCTION`__[]" , when you call  m_pTimeMeasurement->addTimeEntry(`_name`_),addTimeEntry function parameter will be "const char `__FUNCTION__`[]".

So you can concatenate two char variables and pass it

ADD_TIME_ENTRY(strcat(const_cast< char *>(`__FUNCTION`__),"`_start"));
ADD_TIME_ENTRY(strcat(const_cast<char *>(`__FUNCTION`__),"`_stop"));

Comment: If that would really be the case, how do you suppose adding to a constant should work out well?

Comment: addTimeEntry(_name_)  here "`_name`_" is a const,  when this function is called value of variable will be  _name_ = " addTimeEntry()`_start".                         Const here will not allow to change `_name`_ inside addTimeEntry function.

Comment: Yes, but "__FUNCTION__" is a const as you state. So adding to it will first cause a compiler error (since `strcat(char*, const char*)`). The first parameter is the "destination" the second is the "source" (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)) If you cast the const-ness away, which you don't in your example, your program will most likely crash (at the worst possible moment) due to memory corruption.

Comment: It's true that `__FUNCTION__` is an array of `const char`, but you can't concatenate to that.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i forgot to type cast it.

Comment: @savithaA, your cast is **useless**. You can't get rid of constness in this case. Your answer is simply wrong. Even if you was able to cast away constness there would be still another problem - you don't have an additional space where to add another string.